# Can't run pytest + selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

Please help me!
When I trying to run my simple test with pytest+selenium it is not starting. Just nothing happens:

```
import pytest
def test_example(selenium):
    selenium.get('http://www.example.com')
```

Screenshot https://gyazo.com/01d93c221cc6acff0446f1fb473000cb

Note: I'm doing the same at my work PC - it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm idiot (((
Install pytest-selenium
To install pytest-selenium using pip:

$ pip install pytest-selenium

I thought it was enough:
pip install pytest
pip install selenium

Answer (score 1):

I want to note that you can use pytest-selenium but you can also just use pytest and selenium (e.g. selenium==3.0.2 within your requirements.txt) file. The problem that you were facing just looked like a dependency issue.

I also want to note that the screenshot you uploaded contains sensitive information with your staging environment. You should edit it or delete the file entirely.